# Plasma 5 boots into a black screen after installing "kio-extras"

Tags: plasma5, sddm, kde-neon

I have a fresh install of kde neon. I started having issues with the system. I couldn't open system settings. Shortcuts weren't working. Some applications weren't starting (like kolourpaint) and right-clicking konsole made it crash.

I rebooted and now it's only a black screen but I can see the cursor.

Maybe what caused the problem is that I did `sudo apt install kio-extras`

Any guesses? I'm trying to get any useful information from the tty. I tried to restart sddm.

I purged kio-extras and rebooted but that didn't work.

Konsole and kolourpaint were giving me this error respectively

```
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50903) with this library (version 0x50a00)
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = konsole path = /usr/bin pid = 14146
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/konsole 
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi from 
kdeinit
sock_file=/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0
```

---

```
$ kolourpaint
Empty filename passed to function
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50903) with this library (version 0x50a00)
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = kolourpaint path = /usr/bin pid = 13068
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/kolourpaint 
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
sock_file=/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0
Killed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not precisely sure how exactly this happened, but the problem was a partial update. Some packages were updated without others. KDE neon devs have very recently changed from qt 5.9.3 to 5.10

So the solution was get to the tty (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) then connect to the internet (`sudo ifconfig enp3s0 up` where `enp3s0` is the name of the network interface, you can list them by just typing `ifconfig`) and finally do a `sudo apt update`

I had this problem also happen on another machine. It was updating and the electricity went out and when it came back the fix was the same procedure.